# For i.i.d. standard normal variables and $\gamma > 1$, $|X_n| \le (2 \gamma \log{n})^{1/2}$ eventually, almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

I am a beginner in probability theory (also a beginner in analysis) and am currently having trouble with regard to the following problem.

I would like to show:

> Let $X_n$ be a sequence of standard normal random variables. Show that 
>   for any $\gamma > 1$, $|X_n| \le (2 \gamma \log{n})^{1/2}$ for all but finitely many $n$ almost surely.

My attempt is the following:

Consider $\gamma > 1$ and $\{ x: |X_n| \le (2 \gamma \log{n} )^{1/2} \text{ for all but finitely many $n$} \}$.
Then, $\{ x: |X_n| \le (2 \gamma \log{n} )^{1/2} \text{ for all but finitely many $n$} \} 
= \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=N}^\infty \{ x: |X_n| \le (2 \gamma \log{n} )^{1/2} \}$.
We want to show $P(\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=N}^\infty \{ x: |X_n| \le (2 \gamma \log{n} )^{1/2} \}) = 1$;
or to show
$P(\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=N}^\infty \{ x: |X_n| > (2 \gamma \log{n} )^{1/2} \}) = 0$; I show this in the edit.

By way of contradiction, suppose $P(\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=N}^\infty \{ x: |X_n| > (2 \gamma \log{n} )^{1/2} \}) > 0$.
Then, since the infinitely often events are tail events, $P(\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=N}^\infty \{ x: |X_n| > (2 \gamma \log{n} )^{1/2} \}) = 1$ by the Kolomolgorov Zero-One Law

---

EDIT:

By Borel-Cantelli Lemma, it suffices to show $\sum_{n \ge 1} P(|X_n| > (2 \gamma \log{n})^{1/2}) < \infty$.
Since $X_n$ has standard normal distribution,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \ge 1} P(|X_n| > (2 \gamma \log{n})^{1/2}) 
&\le \sum_{n \ge 1} 2 \dfrac{exp( -2\gamma \log{n/2} ) } { \sqrt{2\gamma} \sqrt{2 \pi \log{n}}} \\
&= \sum_{n\ge1} \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2\gamma} n^\gamma \sqrt{2\pi \log{n}}} \\ 
&< \infty
\end{align*}
if $\sqrt{2 \gamma} > \sqrt{2}$.
Since $\gamma > 1$ by hypothesis, $\sum_{n \ge 1} P(|X_n| > (2 \gamma \log{n})^{1/2}) < \infty$
and by Borel-Cantelli Lemma, $P(\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{M=N}^\infty \{ |X_n| > (2 \gamma \log{n} )^{1/2} \}) = 0$.

---

From here, I am stuck.
Is there another approach? Any insight?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Continue what you started, with Borel-Cantelli lemma. To do so, you will need to estimate $P( |X_n| > (2 \gamma \log{n} )^{1/2})$.

Comment: ((Note that each event $\{x:\text{something}\}$ in your post should read $\{\text{something}\}$.))

Comment: @Did Thank you; I found the bounding expression from somewhere around here. I am trying to understand where that bound is coming from. Do you know any source by any chance?

Comment: "I am trying to understand where that bound is coming from" The bound on the normal distribution$P(|Z|>z)$, you mean?

Comment: @Did Ah I see; it is from comparing the integral with the discrete sum. Right? Incidentally I think I discovered that the sum must be multiplied by 2.

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $